# How to make 'ő' and 'ű' work in Java?

Tags: applet

```
String word = inputField.getText();
int wordLength = word.length();
boolean backWord = false;
boolean longWord = false;
String backArray[]=new String[6];
backArray[0] = "a";
backArray[1] = "á";
backArray[2] = "ö";
backArray[3] = "ő";
backArray[4] = "ü";
backArray[5] = "ű";
for (int i = 0;i < wordLength ;i ++ ) { 
  String character = word.substring(i, i + 1);
  for (int j = 0;j < 5;j ++) { 
    if (character.equals(backArray[j])) {
      backWord = true;
    }
  } 
} 
if (backWord) {
  outputField.setText(word+"ban");
} 
else {
  outputField.setText(word+"ben");
}
```

This is the code I wrote for an applet for conjugating Hungarian nouns while taking vowel harmony into consideration. For the unaware, the TL;DR of vowel harmony is that Hungarian has lots of suffixes and you can determine which suffix to use based on the vowels in a word.

This code works fine for all the vowels, except for ő and ű. So if my input is 'szálloda', the output will be 'szállodaban'. However, if my input is 'idő' (weather) the output will be 'időben', though it should be 'időban' according to the code.

I assumed this is because java somehow doesn't recognize these two letters because the code works fine for the other ones. Is that the problem? And if so, how do I solve it?

Comment: Are source code and `javac -encoding` both UTF-8? ISO 8859-2 and Unicode seem to differ.